# External modules security

Tags: licensing, desktop-application

I am developing some external modules for an application.

These modules are BPL files and if present in the application folder the application loads them and uses whatever is available inside.

How can I prevent the sharing of these modules by my clients?

I need them to be authorized to use the modules (module by module).

To have some sort of license, registration of the module, what is the best method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify the modules so that on loading they check for the existence of required licenses and registrations.

I assume your application has a license, in which case you can include them in the same licenses format, or create separate license files that can be included in the application as well.